# Trying to get external cron working

Tags: civimail, cron-job

I'm trying to get the external url-based cron to run and I keep getting fatal errors. I don't really want to debug the PHP code. Can anyone help me?

The URL I use has the correct username, password and sitekey:

http://predigerforum.ch/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=xxx@xxx&pass=xx&key=xxx

I get the following message:

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRM/Core/Config.php' (include_path='.') in /nhldata/631/106631/data/web/predigerforum/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php on line 30

It looks like there is a path configuration error, but I cannot find any mistakes in the settings file. I've checked quite a few forum entries and things look correct...

Thanks for any help

David

Comment: I'm using CiviCRM 4.6.4 with the latest Wordpress version

Comment: It looks like the setting of the base path is incorrect. I've just tried the url again and got:

Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/nhldata/wp-includes/pluggable.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/nhldata/631/106631/data/web:/usr/local/php55/share/pear:/var/tmp/php:/tmp:/usr/local/php55/lib64) in /nhldata/631/106631/data/web/predigerforum/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php on line 360

Comment: Warning: require_once(/nhldata/wp-includes/pluggable.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /nhldata/631/106631/data/web/predigerforum/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php on line 360

Comment: Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/nhldata/wp-includes/pluggable.php' (include_path='.:/nhldata/631/106631/data/web/predigerforum/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm:/nhldata/631/106631/data/web/predigerforum/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages:.:/nhldata/631/106631/data/web/predigerforum/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/:/nhldata/631/106631/data/web/predigerforum/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm//packages:.') in

Comment: /nhldata/631/106631/data/web/predigerforum/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php on line 360

Comment: I cleaned up the behaviour by adding 

    if (!strpos($dir, '\/wordpress\/')) {   // **DC** 2015.08.27
      return FALSE;                     //    only search within wordpress structure!
    }                                   //

at the start of public function validInstallDir($dir) in WordPress.php, which stopped it complaining about base dir violations (this assumes wordpress in the path, which is true for me). The cron even worked once, but now when I run it I get...

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Function "is_admin()" is missing, even though WordPress is the user framework.' in /nhldata/631/106631/data/web/predigerforum/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Base.php:255 Stack trace: #0 /nhldata/631/106631/data/web/predigerforum/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(192): CRM_Utils_System_Base->theme('<div id="crm-co...', false ... /nhldata/631/106631/data/web/predigerforum/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Base.php on line 255

Comment: I've upgraded successfully to 4.6.8 but still get that exception: "Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Function "is_admin()" is missing, even though WordPress is the user framework.'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of messing around, I upgraded to 4.6.8 and then made a clean copy of the latest civicrm 4.6.8 files into the civicrm/CRM subdirectory, and the cron job ran properly. However, my Wordpress installation failed, because there are multiple Wordpress installations on the server and a search from the top root caused basedir restriction errors (and would probably have failed for that reason...).

The fix was to add the following lines to civicrm.settings.php, just before the section "do not add anything below this":

if (!defined('CIVICRM_CMSDIR')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_CMSDIR', '/nhldata/631/106631/data/web/predigerforum/htdocs/wordpress/' );
}

It was important to include the "/wordpress/" at the end!

I'm not sure that this overriding parameter is really documented, though. I found it referred to in a forum post.